# What does the circle around a note mean in a guitar chord diagram?

Tags: guitar, chords, notation

I'm trying to play E/G#. I found this, but what is that symbol on the 4th string?

[image]

Comment: Why is the e1 string X-ed out? It's an E Major chord after all.

Comment: The A string could be played on 2nd fret, and yes, what's wrong with top open ?

Answer (score 19):

The circle around the dot usually means that that note is the ROOT note of the chord. In this case, E!

Comment: You are correct, sir.